# extend css form through php code

Tags: php, css

I have the below php MySQL query code and want to present the results in a table within a form.

```
            <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM persons order by date_entered DESC LIMIT 5";
                    $response = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    if($response){
                    echo '<div id="frm"> <h2> Last 5 candidates entered </h2> <table align="left">
                    <tr>
                            <td align="left"><b>First Name</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Email</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Sex</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>City</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Phone Number</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Education</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Salary</b></td>
                    </tr>';

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td align="left">' . '<a href="person.php?id=' . $row["person_id"] . '">' . $row["first_name"] . " " .$row['last_name'] . '</a>' . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['sex'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['city'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['education'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                    } else {
                    echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
                    echo mysqli_error($con);
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

The form is defined in CSS style with the height set to auto however, the form dimensions do not extend to the length of the results, it only goes 160px and then stops with the rest of the query results displayed in the body.

```
#frm {
align: center;
font-family: "verdana";
font-size: 13px;
border: solid gray 1px;
width: 700px;
height: auto;
border-radius: 2px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: white;
padding: 50px;
}
```

[form not extending to the length of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1OJX.png)

My obvious question is, how do I make the form extend to the length of results?

Thanks!

Comment: some time this also happens if any tag has not ended properly. I see frm div tag is not completed in this code.

Comment: This is not something you'd want to use PHP for. I suspect you have unclosed tags or some float issues, but you'd need to share more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try floating the #frm element or adding:

```
display:table;
```

to it.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this did the trick! I am guessing display:table; would affect the form if I was to use it elsewhere and for other than tables or not? Thanks again!

Comment: All we've really done is define that the #frm div should stretch to it's contents. The layout of content inside would depend on what CSS declarations you added to them. As your example is a native HTML table, no further markup is required. There's a great article with more info here: http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero. Also make sure to close the div element as others have pointed out or else you'll likely run into problems further down the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan, really appreciated. I have a </div> further down the code outside the php tags. I am unsure if this is correct or if I should close it with an echo'</div> inside the php tags? Thanks again. Best, Roberto